# Testing Angular 4 HttpTestingController with catch and _throw error logic

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have Service using *HttpClient* using a POST request, if the server responds with and error I need to catch it format the message and re-throw it. I have tried to test this scenario, but failed to mock the test. The HttpTestingController is not sending my custom error message back nor is it catching it on the service and re-throwing it, Whats the proper way to do this

the service code :

```
 login(credentials: LoginPayload): Observable<LoginSuccessPayload> {

      return this.http.post<LoginSuccessPayload>('/api/auth/signin', credentials)
             .map(res => {authUser: res.user})
             .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (error.message) {
                    return _throw(error);
                }
                return _throw({message: 'Notification.LoginError'});
             });

 }
```

now the test

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [AuthService]
    });

    authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
});

it('should format the error message', (done) => {
    const credentials = {userName: 'bob', password: '123'} as LoginPayload;
    const mockErrorResponse = {message: 'failed to login'} ;

    authService.login(credentials).subscribe(() => {}, err => {
        expect(err.message).toEqual(mockErrorResponse.message);
        done();
    });

    const req = httpMock.expectOne('/api/auth/signin');
    req.error(new ErrorEvent(mockErrorResponse.message));

    httpMock.verify();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late to this but I thought I'd answer this anyway for anyone who stumbles upon this like I did. I find the complete [lack of documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests) on angular.io around this error case to be insane. "Figure it out yourself", I guess?

Anyway...the approach I took was to avoid `.error()` altogether since it didn't seem to be as easy as using `.flush()` and the documentation does [state](https://angular.io/api/common/http/testing/TestRequest#flush) it can be used for both successful and unsuccessful responses.

Here's how I would update your code to use flush:

```
it('should format the error message', (done) => {
    const credentials = {userName: 'bob', password: '123'} as LoginPayload;
    const mockErrorResponse = {message: 'failed to login'} ;

    authService.login(credentials).subscribe(() => {}, err => {
        // NOTE: err.error.message
        expect(err.error.message).toEqual(mockErrorResponse.message);
        done();
    });

    const req = httpMock.expectOne('/api/auth/signin');
    req.flush({message: mockErrorResponse.message}, {status: 400, statusText: ''});

    httpMock.verify();
});
```

The one annoying part about this update with `HttpClient` in `@angular/common/http` as opposed to `Http` in `@angular/http` is that the error message is now a property of `err.error` in the `subscribe()` rather than `err` itself.

So if you're like me and you're upgrading from one to the other, all references to `err.message` must now be updated to `err.error.message`. I hope this helps.

Comment: I like your solution, and it works for me too. But what makes the flush() in your code return an error to the subscriber? Aren't you supposed to invoke req.error() to emulate an error?

Comment: @YakovFain The second argument to .flush() containing an object with properties such as the status code.

Comment: I tried flush() with the status 200, but it still goes to the error handler of the subscriber. This works for me:
```req.error(new ErrorEvent ('The error text') );
...
.subscribe(() => {},
          errorResponse => expect(errorResponse.error.type).toEqual('The error text')
      );
```

Comment: If you're flushing successful responses you don't need the second argument, just pass it the response - .flush(yourResponse)

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions which worked out for me.

To begin with I'd replace this:

```
authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
```

with this:

```
const testBed = getTestBed();
authService = testBed.get(AuthService);
httpMock = testBed.get(HttpTestingController);
```

I think the point here is that you fail to actually access the Testbed.

I'd also ad a verification that your request is a POST request with the following:

```
expect(req.request.method).toBe("POST");
```

These are the things I would add on first thought.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the angular documentation approach [link](https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests) and it worked for me using the req.error. Hope this helps..

```
it('should handle an error', inject([HttpClient, HttpTestingController], (http: HttpClient, httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {

    http.get<any>('http://localhost:4200/api/data').subscribe(
        response => fail('should fail with a 403 error'),
        error => {
            expect(error.status).toBe(403);
        }
    );

    // Mocking rejects with a 403 error
    let mockRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(req =>  
                        req.url === 'http://localhost:4200/api/data');
    let error = new ErrorEvent('ERROR');
    mockRequest.error(error, { status: 403 ,statusText: 'Invalid access.'});

    mockHttp.verify();
}));
```